# Is there a text object for current line?

Tags: cursor-motions, custom-text-object

- Is there a text object for current line?
- Is there a text object for `^$`?

Comment: There exists a [plugin](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-line)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are crude "line" text objects:

```
xnoremap il g_o0
onoremap il :normal vil<CR>
xnoremap al $o0
onoremap al :normal val<CR>
```

And a crude "buffer" text object:

```
xnoremap i% GoggV
onoremap i% :normal vi%<CR>
```

---EDIT---

An "operator" is a command that doesn't do anything by itself: `d`, `y`, etc.

Pressing those keys put you in "operator-pending mode", where Vim waits for you to tell it what you want it to operate on… with an "operator-pending motion".

You can use `:omap` or `:onoremap` to define custom operator-pending motions. The technique used here is inspired by `:help omap-info`:

1. you define a visual mode mapping that covers the desired area,
2. you use that mapping in an operator-pending mapping.

Note that I used `:onoremap` because `il`, `al` and `i%` don't already exist. If you are overriding an existing motion or text-object — say `ip` — you must use a recursive mapping: `:omap`.

`:help :map-operator` describes a slightly more advanced method.

See `:help v_o` for `o` in visual mode.

Comment: Cool. Would you mind explaining a few bits of it? What is `o` (operator pending mode) in onoremap? What does `o` in visual mode do? I would guess that it is "other side", because it seems to jump to the other side of a selection... How do i find `:h`on it? I can't find it with `:h x_o` or `:h o`.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest an additional solution, to use ^ instead of 0 (so the line starts at the beginning of the first character:

```
xnoremap il g_o^
onoremap il :normal vil<CR>
xnoremap al $o^
onoremap al :normal val<CR>
```

This way if we do "change in line" it will respect the indentation level.

Comment: There is also a plugin providing this functionality by vim master kana: https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-line/blob/master/doc/textobj-line.txt