# Create a motion?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions

I find it very strange that I can't find this question anywhere...

I made a mapping `nnoremap <leader>C /\u<CR>` to go to the next capital letter. I thought it would be useful to edit camelCase stuff, so if I had something like `oneTwoThree` and I wanted to change it to `oneFourThree` I could just put cursor on the `T` and do `c<leader>C`. However this does not work. Is there an easy way to make this work?

Edit: I accidentally found out that pressing `<leader>Cc<leader>` does what I want, I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you tell us what your mapping is?

Comment: @BLayer `nnoremap <leader>C /\u<CR>`

Comment: @BLayer I wish this to work for any operator. For example if I did `d<leader>C` it would delete, if I did `y<leader>C` would yank, etc.

Comment: Ah, ok. Got it. Then you'll want to look at the `omap` family of  mapping commands as you're in an "operator-pending" state after you hit `c`.

Comment: Here's an example: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/is-there-a-text-object-for-current-line/6102#6102

Comment: Also useful: https://medium.com/usevim/custom-motions-part-1-e5be6d745d23 ... basically you want to create a "custom motion" and while this isn't strictly possible (motions are defined in Vim source code), you can usually get what you need with `omap` and friends. Alternatively use a plugin like[Camel Case Motion](https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nnoremap` adds your mapping to Normal mode only. But after `c` you are in Operator-pending mode, where `<leader>C` has no effect.

So it suffices to do just `noremap <silent><leader>C /\u<CR>` instead.

`noremap` is a convenient command to register mapping in three modes (normal, visual and operator-pending) at once.