# Select the current line without moving the cursor

Tags: normal-mode

If my cursor is in the middle of a line, how can I select the whole active line (i.e. without the possible indentations at the beginning of the line, so between `^` and `$`) without moving the cursor to the beginning or end of the line? I was thinking if there something similar to inner motions (e.g. `diw` or `yip` where the command is executed to the word or paragraph from where ever my cursor is inside the word or paragraph). I though maybe there is some *imaginary* `vil`?

Comment: The obvious answer would be `V` or is that not working for some reason?

Comment: `V` selects the whole line, including the indentations.

Comment: In normal visual mode, as opposed to visual line mode, the cursor has to be at one or the other end of the visually selected text.  Think of how you select text on browser with mouse.  Can you put the cursor anywhere else other than the end of the selected text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a text object for current line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/is-there-a-text-object-for-current-line)

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6101/23502) could help you answering yours.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt that solution also includes the indentation white spaces

Comment: What do you plan to do with the selected line? A lot of vim commands operate on the current line without having to select it first. Commands that accept a range will operate on the current line by default. Notepad forces you to select text. Is this a case of [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: If you dont want to include the indents try saving the current cursor location to a marker and restoring it later, like `mm^v$y\`m` copies the line without the leading indents.

Comment: @Student Doesn't [the second answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21238/343) do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

The cursor is always at one end of the visual selection so what you are asking for is not possible.

But… you don't really select thing just for the fun, do you? You select them to do something with them, right?

Maybe what you actually want is the cursor to come back to where it was before you entered visual mode *after* you are done? In that case, you might want to provide more context, i.e. what you want to do with the selection, etc.

Maybe what you want to do could be better done *without* visual selection to begin with? In that case, a custom pseudo-text object might help.

It is difficult to get from your question.

For what it's worth, these are the pseudo-text objects I settled on after posting the answer linked in the comments:

```
xnoremap il g_o^
onoremap il :<C-u>normal vil<CR>
xnoremap al $o0
onoremap al :<C-u>normal val<CR>
```

The first one, `il`, covers the line *without* leading and trailing whitespace while the second one, `al`, covers the whole line, including EOL.

The problem I tried to work around with these pseudo-text object is that Vim only gives us a "line" primitive that comes with a lot of bagage:

- it is line-wise,
- it includes EOL,
- it includes leading and trailing space.

Moreover, we have things like `yy` or `dd` but we don't really have a proper "line" motion/text object (and no, `:help _` is not exactly that), let alone a "content of the line" one.

My `il` pseudo-text object gives me that missing "content of the line" primitive ("quote this line", "cut this line character-wise", etc.), while its `al` friend acts as an idiomatic mirror.